# How to add result in subscriber to the property of the array of objects

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have this interface:

```
export interface ImageInfo {
  imageurl: string;
  time: string;
  location:string
}
```

Here how it defined in the component:

```
 imageInfo: ImageInfo[];
```

Also, I have this variable:

```
imgsurl : string[];
```

I fetch images url from server and store them in imgsurl class:

```
httpservice(id).subscribe(response => {this.imgurls = response.results})
```

then I iterate on the imgsurl array and assign it to the imageInfo.

my question is it possible to add response.results inside subscribe directly to imageurl property of the
imageInfo array?

Comment: Please add http response data in question.

Comment: @SantoshShinde the imgurls get array of strings from the response.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple things to note here

1. Yes, you could assign it directly to the `imageInfo` array using [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function.

```js
httpservice(id).subscribe(response => {
  this.imageInfo = response.results.map(result => {
    return <ImageInfo>{
      imageurl: result,
      time: '',
      location: ''
    };
  });
});
```

2. Now you see the obvious issue here. The `response` inside the subscription holds (as far as we know from the question) only the `imageurl` property of the `ImageInfo` object. So you have 3 options

- Assign empty strings like I did
- Assign the properties if the `response` contains them

```js
httpservice(id).subscribe(response => {
  this.imageInfo = response.map(r => { // <-- hypothetical - only works if `reponse` is an array
    return <ImageInfo>{
      imageurl: r.result,
      time: r.time, // <-- hypothetical
      location: r.location // <-- hypothetical
    };
  });
});
```

- Make the properties optional and skip them

Interface

```js
export interface ImageInfo {
  imageurl?: string;
  time?: string;
  location?: string
}
```

Controller

```js
httpservice(id).subscribe(response => {
  this.imageInfo = response.results.map(result => {
    return <ImageInfo>{
      imageurl: result,
    };
  });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You have created variable `imgsurl : string[];`. It should be `imgurls: string[];`.

And change http call to

```
httpservice(id).subscribe((response: any) => {this.imgurls = response.results});
```